# How to collect fields in a struct vector into separate arrays efficiently

Tags: loops, rust

I managed to make it work (see below example), but this requires multiple iterations of the array.

Is there a way to iterate the vector only once?

```rust
struct Vx {
    pub a: f32,
    pub b: f32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut varr = Vec::new();
    varr.push(Vx { a: 0., b: 0. });
    varr.push(Vx { a: 1., b: 1. });
    varr.push(Vx { a: 2., b: 2. });

    let a: Vec<f32> = varr.iter().map(|v| v.a).collect();
    let b: Vec<f32> = varr.iter().map(|v| v.b).collect();

    println!("a: {:?}", a);
    println!("b: {:?}", b);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` + `unzip` works excellently for exactly two fields, but for an arbitrary number of fields you can always use the more general-purpose `fold` and unpack them into any kind of structure:

```
struct Vx {
    pub a: f32,
    pub b: f32,
    pub c: f32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut varr = Vec::new();
    varr.push(Vx {
        a: 0.,
        b: 0.,
        c: 1.,
    });
    varr.push(Vx {
        a: 1.,
        b: 1.,
        c: 2.,
    });
    varr.push(Vx {
        a: 2.,
        b: 2.,
        c: 3.,
    });

    let len = varr.len();
    let (a, b, c) = varr.iter().fold(
        (
            Vec::with_capacity(len),
            Vec::with_capacity(len),
            Vec::with_capacity(len),
        ),
        |(mut a, mut b, mut c), v| {
            a.push(v.a);
            b.push(v.b);
            c.push(v.c);
            (a, b, c)
        },
    );

    println!("a: {:?}", a); // a: [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]
    println!("b: {:?}", b); // b: [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]
    println!("c: {:?}", c); // c: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
}
```

Comment: You can also use `itertools`' [`multiunzip`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/fn.multiunzip.html) to take care of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` and `unzip`:

```rs
struct Vx {
    pub a: f32,
    pub b: f32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut varr = Vec::new();
    varr.push(Vx { a: 0., b: 0. });
    varr.push(Vx { a: 1., b: 1. });
    varr.push(Vx { a: 2., b: 2. });

    let (a, b): (Vec<f32>, Vec<f32>) = varr.iter().map(|v| (v.a, v.b)).unzip();

    println!("a: {:?}", a);
    println!("b: {:?}", b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with iterators as shown in the other answers. However this is a case where a plain procedural solution might be more suitable:

```
struct Vx {
    pub a: f32,
    pub b: f32,
    pub c: f32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut varr = Vec::new();
    varr.push(Vx {
        a: 0.,
        b: 0.,
        c: 1.,
    });
    varr.push(Vx {
        a: 1.,
        b: 1.,
        c: 2.,
    });
    varr.push(Vx {
        a: 2.,
        b: 2.,
        c: 3.,
    });

    let len = varr.len();
    let mut a = Vec::with_capacity (len);
    let mut b = Vec::with_capacity (len);
    let mut c = Vec::with_capacity (len);
    for v in &varr {
        a.push (v.a);
        b.push (v.b);
        c.push (v.c);
    }
    // Optional, make immutable:
    let (a, b, c) = (a, b, c);

    println!("a: {:?}", a); // a: [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]
    println!("b: {:?}", b); // b: [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]
    println!("c: {:?}", c); // c: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bde84e108f9ebef6e5fd61313a830526)